# How do you create a viewmodel with a savedStateHandle and another argument?

Tags: android, viewmodel

This is my viewModel

```
class ViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle, private val dataSource: DataSource) :ViewModel()
```

This is my viewModelProviderFactory

```
class ViewModelProviderFactory(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val dataSource: DataSource
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ViewModel(savedStateHandle, dataSource) as T
    }
}
```

In MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels()
...
```

I do not know how to get a `savedStateHandle` to pass to the factory so that I can create a viewModel.

Comment: Check this: https://www.rockandnull.com/viewmodel-savedstate/

Comment: Thank you so much. You rock. But please correct the line that reads `override val model by viewModels<MyViewModel> ...`. Just delete `override`

Answer (score 5):

You can use other create method of `ViewModelProvider.Factory`:

```kotlin
class ViewModelProviderFactory(
    private val dataSource: DataSource
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>, extras: CreationExtras): T {
        return ViewModel(extras.createSavedStateHandle(), dataSource) as T
    }
}
```

And when initializing ViewModel by `by viewModels()` syntax, don't forget to pass the factory parameter:

```kotlin
private val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels(factory = ViewModelProviderFactory(dataSource))
```

There is also another way to avoid the headache of creating ViewModelProvider.Factory that using hilt, you can refer this link to try hilt: https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model